# Django strips headers containing an underscore

Tags: django, header

I am using a Django 1.7.5 application which is parsing headers which contains underscores.

I read that Django strips headers containing an underscore. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25048. Is there a workaround to make the headers with underscore work? I cannot modify the rest client.

Comment: Note that Django only strips headers with underscores when using `manage.py runserver`. In other cases, it's your webserver that strips them.

Comment: Is there a way to disable this "feature" on the development webserver?

Comment: It's hardcoded. You can't change the behaviour without changing Django's code.